# emit two events from one socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to listen two different events from one socket;
Both together do not work, only the first to be emitted could be listen.

```
//server
​
_this.nsp.volatile.emit('event1', foo);
_this.nsp.volatile.emit('event2', bar);
​

//client
​
socket.on('event1', function(data){
    //THIS ONE WORK
    console.log("event1");
});
socket.on('event2', function(data){
    //THIS ONE NOT
    console.log("event2");
});
```

On this example, the `event1` will work, but the `event2` not.

If I emit first `event2`, `event2` will work but not `event1`.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Using `volatile` _does_ mean that messages are allowed to be dropped for whatever reason...

Comment: Hum... Yes but how could that be related to my problem?

Comment: I can imagine that, depending on which transport is in use, volatile messages may not all be delivered when sent in quick succession. Have you tried using "regular" messages?

Comment: Not really, I thought volatile could drop some messages but I didn't know it would simply not send anything on consecutive send... Knowing I don't mind receiving all messages and only the server need to send data, does removing volatile  will be enought to make it work? I will try tomorrow I left the work now and I don't have access to the code :/

Comment: I don't know if it'll work, but it's worth trying =D Otherwise, you could always enable [debugging](http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/) to see what's happening.

Comment: Sure :D To bad I can't test it now, I'm telling you by tomorrow how researches goes!

Comment: It's working without volatile mode on the second event. Apparently you was right, emitting two volatile events one after the other result by the drop of the second one. Add an answer I you want me to valid you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** if you want to ensure that messages are sent out, don't use `volatile`.

Using `volatile` means that messages are allowed to be dropped. In other words: you cannot rely on them being delivered *at all*, or in any particular order.

I ran a quick test with code similar to this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.volatile.emit('event1', '1');
  socket.volatile.emit('event2', '2');
});
```

Neither message is being delivered (in my setup, anyway). The reason for this, as far as I can tell from debugging output, is because the server and the client are still negotiating about which transport to use when the messages are sent. Because they are volatile, the server doesn't queue them up to send them out once the negotiations have completed.

Something similar happens when you emit the messages after some waiting:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    socket.volatile.emit('event1', '1');
    socket.volatile.emit('event2', '2');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Here, the first message is received but the second one isn't (this seems to be similar to your situation). The debug log shows this:

```
  socket.io:client writing packet {"type":2,"data":["event1","1"],"nsp":"/"} +1s
  socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["event1","1"],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["event1","1"],"nsp":"/"} as 2["event1","1"] +1ms
  engine:socket sending packet "message" (2["event1","1"]) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "42["event1","1"]" +0ms
  socket.io:client writing packet {"type":2,"data":["event2","2"],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["event2","2"],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["event2","2"],"nsp":"/"} as 2["event2","2"] +0ms
```

From that, I have to conclude that the second message *is* encoded but isn't being delivered to the `engine.io` part, which handles the actual communication. It doesn't say why not, though. Perhaps it's because the first event is still being sent out, but that's just conjecture on my part.